# Why holes in a semiconductor are associated with a net positive charge?

Tags: semiconductor-physics

I am clear with the idea that holes move in direction of electric field because of motion of bound electrons that get just some energy to jump into next hole.But i am confused with giving holes a positive charge.

I understood that in intrinsic semiconductor removal of electron is associated with less screening of some protons so their is a positive charge effect that can be made associated with location where electron left i.e hole ,so some people and textbook say hole has a net positive charge.like this shown in my book and answered to question [Why Holes have an effective positive charge?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/526259/250789)

[image]

But my question is if we apply this positive charge to hole in p type semiconductor then semiconductor is no more neutral that is a contradiction to property given in my textbook.Please consider explaning how in this case we can assiciate the hole with a positive charge.[image]

In this above picture we can see how neutral charge of semiconductor is affected when we associate postive charge with holes.(Note in picture already 10 protons are screened with 10 electrons so it shows +4)

[image]picture of textbook that says semiconductor should be neutral.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are holes a fundamental particle? Are they a real thing or just a construct?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/372079/are-holes-a-fundamental-particle-are-they-a-real-thing-or-just-a-construct)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, think of it this way,
you've got a bunch of atoms all lined up and having equal number of protons and electrons (say, Si atoms) and hence are neutral as a whole

Now, you add a trivalent atom (which, by the way, is also neutral)-like Al-and this leaves a "space" in the arrangement, as seen in your textbook.

If an electron in the neighborhood jumps into the gap, it leaves a gap at the point where it originally was. Since the electron is no longer in the gap, the *previously* neutral region becomes a "positive gap", or what we call a hole.

But at the same time, the *Al atom becomes negatively charged*, as it has 14 electrons and 13 protons.
Therefore, the net charge on the Semiconductor adds up to is zero.

Comment: Thank you for explaining in correct way   :)

Answer (score 2):

A hole results from removing an electron from the valence band, not from removing it from the semiconductor. On the level of the textbook: an electron that was bound to an atom now has high energy that allows it to move freely across the semiconductor, as if it were an electron in a metal. The remaining vacancy can be filled by other electrons, thus behaving as if it were an effective positive charge. If an electric field is applied, the electron and the whole will move in the opposite directions. However as a whole the semiconductor remains neutral: for every hole there is a free moving electron.

Answer (score 0):

As you correctly pointed out, holes can’t be positively charged because then the system won’t be electrically neutral. What they actually mean is that the system is more positively (less negatively) charged when compared to the presence of **all** valence electrons present in a particular atom of the lattice.

Comment: The semiconductor is neutral. There is no net charge.

Comment: I didn’t refute that. But I believe I wasn’t clear in my answer, which I hopefully have clarified. Thank you @JonCuster for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

> my question is if we apply this positive charge to hole in p type semiconductor then semiconductor is no more neutral

There is a big difference between something *being* positively charged and *acting as if* it were positively charged. Holes just act as if they were.